# JArray - How to remove elements that are not contained in another list -fastest/best performance way

Tags: c#, json, performance, json.net

This is the context of my problem:

There is an `JArray` with thousands of elements. It is **umbrellas** (`JArray`) in the sample.

There is another small list with only hundred of elements. It is called **umbrellasToBeRemovedIds** (`List<string>`).

I am trying this approach to remove these umbrellas:

```
foreach (string umbrellaToRemoveId in umbrellasToBeRemovedIds)
{
    umbrellas.FirstOrDefault(o => o["Id"].Value<string>() == umbrellaToRemoveId)?.Remove();
}
```

Consider umbrellasToBeRemovedIds have smaller size than umbrellas. 
What is the fastest way (performance wise) to remove elements from this umbrellas `JArray` ?

Comment: Instead of trying to modify a JArray, use a regular array and `Except` to the differences, then create a JArray from it. Or you could create HashSet instances with the strings you want. HashSet is optimized for fast set-based operations

Comment: Make *umbrellasToBeRemovedIds* a HasSet. Iterate on *umbrellas* and leave/remove the item by checking its existance in HashSet

Comment: @Eser , can I remove elements from a JArray(umbrellas) being iterated?

Comment: @AlbertoMontellano `somelist.ToList()` would do the trick. If you post a copy/paste ready code, you can get a working code as answer... I think your reps are enough to know that

Comment: @Eser, the exception "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." will be got if you remove elements from JArray being iterated. What do you mean with ToList?

Comment: `jArray.ToList()` would make a shallow copy and you wouldn't get that exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues specific to `JArray` to keep in mind with respect to performance:

1. [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) does not have an API equivalent to [`List<T>.RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) that removes multiple entries efficiently using the shift-down-and-resize-once algorithm shown in the [`List<T>` reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,82567b42bbfc416e,references).  Instead it has [`Clear()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Clear.htm) to remove all items, [`RemoveAt()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_RemoveAt.htm) to remove a single item, and [`ReplaceAll()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_ReplaceAll.htm) to efficiently replace the current contents with different contents.

   Since `RemoveAt()` as implemented removes an entry from an internal `List<JToken>` and shifts the subsequent list items down, removing `k` items from a `JArray` of size `n` would be `O(n*k)`, which is probably not good enough for your application.
2. There is a bi-directional reference between parents and children in the `JToken` hierarchy:

   - [`JToken.Children()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Children.htm) iterates through all child tokens of a given token;
   - [`JToken.Parent`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parent.htm) gets the parent of a given token.

   As a result, a `JToken` cannot have two parents, and if you attempt to add a `JToken` that already has a parent to another parent, it is *cloned*.  I.e. if `array` is a `JArray` then

   ```
   array[i] = array[i+1];
   ```

   Will clone the array entry at index `i+1` rather than simply adding it twice to the array.  (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469642/3744182) for details why this happens.)

   As a result, naively implementing the shift-down-and-resize-once algorithm in applications code will have terrible performance as many array entries get cloned in the process.

Putting the above points together, the following extension methods should have the best algorithmic performance in removing `k` items from a `JArray` of size `n`:

```
public static partial class JTokenExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all the elements whose values, as defined by `selector`, belong to the collection of incoming values
    /// </summary>
    public static int RemoveAll<T>(this JArray array, IEnumerable<T> values, Func<JToken, T> selector, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        if (array == null || values == null || selector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var set = new HashSet<T>(values, comparer);
        return array.RemoveAll(i => set.Contains(selector(i)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate.
    /// </summary>
    public static int RemoveAll(this JArray array, Predicate<JToken> match)
    {
        if (array == null || match == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var arrayCount = array.Count;
        var toKeep = array.Where(i => !match(i)).ToList();
        var keepCount = toKeep.Count;
        if (keepCount == arrayCount)
            return 0; // Nothing to remove.
        array.ReplaceAll(toKeep);
        return arrayCount - keepCount;
    }
}
```

Which you would call as follows:

```
umbrellas.RemoveAll(umbrellasToBeRemovedIds, i => (string)i["id"]);
```

This should have performance of `O(n + k + k*log(k))` where the `k*log(k)` term is the (presumed) complexity of building the hash set of values.  Note I am assuming that the `"id"` properties are unique.  If there can be duplicated ids in both lists and you only want to remove a number of items from the `array` equal to the number of matching duplicate ids, then a more complex algorithm would be required.

As for potential point-optimizations, such as *is it faster to do `(string)i["id"]` or `i["Id"].Value<string>()`*, I direct you to Eric Lippert's article *[Which is faster, `QueryLightBulbFrobStatusEx()` or `__WGetBulbFrobberState2()`?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)*