# How to remove an item from a JSON string by value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am working in C#. I want to load a JSON string and delete an item by value. For example, in the following JSON, I want to remove the value of 2. So, in the resulting JSON string, the Dallas Store should have been removed.

```
[ 
   { 
      "text":"Select Store",
      "value":""
   },
   { 
      "text":"Austin Store",
      "value":"1"
   },
   { 
      "text":"Dallas Store",
      "value":"2"
   },
   { 
      "text":"Houston Store",
      "value":"3"
   },
   { 
      "text":"Chicago Store",
      "value":"4"
   },
   { 
      "text":"Los Angeles Store",
      "value":"5"
   }
]
```

I could parse the string with Newton Soft's JArray, loop through and add all the stores except the Dallas one in a new JArray. I am wondering is there a simpler Linq method to work on the JArray which will remove the expected item.

Comment: stores.RemoveAll(s => s.value == 2)?

Comment: `var array = JArray.Parse(json); array.SelectTokens("[?(@.value == '2')]").ToList().ForEach(i => i.Remove());`?

Comment: @aardvark - [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) doesn't have a [`RemoveAll(Predicate<JToken> predicate)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_RemoveAll.htm) method that takes a predicate, see [JArray - How to remove elements that are not contained in another list -fastest/best performance way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48934455/3744182).

Comment: @Massey - demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mi8Exd

Comment: Ah, sorry, @dbc - I had made my comment before the original question had been reformatted and didn't notice he was deserializing into a JArray.

Comment: Hi dbc, actually your solution works perfectly. I had the error because I was using a dynamic object in my code. Once I cast it to a string, it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options here since [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) does not have a [`RemoveAll(Predicate<JToken> match)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_RemoveAll.htm) method.

Firstly, you can use [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) to find all `JArray` items for which `value == 2` and then remove them as follows:

```
var array = JArray.Parse(jsonString);

array.SelectTokens("[?(@.value == '2')]")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => i.Remove());
```

The expression `[?(@.value == '2')]` is a JSONPath query; for details and documentation see *[# JSONPath - XPath for JSON](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)* and *[Querying JSON with complex JSON Path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)*.

Note that this may have quadratic performance in the number of items to be removed, and so might be unacceptably slow if you are removing a large number of items.

Secondly, you can grab `JTokenExtensions.RemoveAll(this JArray array, Predicate<JToken> match)` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48937479/3744182) to *[JArray - How to remove elements that are not contained in another list -fastest/best performance way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48934455/3744182)*:

```
public static partial class JTokenExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RemoveAll(this JArray array, Predicate<JToken> match)
    {
        if (array == null || match == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        array.ReplaceAll(array.Where(i => !match(i)).ToList());
    }
}
```

Then remove your desired items as follows:

```
array.RemoveAll(i => (string)i["value"] == "2");
```

This will have linear performance in the number of items to be removed.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mi8Exd).

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!