# Remove JObject from JArray when the value matches an item in a list

Tags: c#, json, list, json.net

I have an JArray as:

```
{[  
  {
    "value": "275869398483537748",
    "label": "AbhiTest1"
  },
  {
    "value": "275869398491926942",
    "label": "AbhiTest21"
  },
  {
    "value": "275869398487731826",
    "label": "AbhiTest3"
  }
]}
```

And I have a list as: `List<String> IdsToDelete = new List<string>();`
and `IdsToDelete` has an item whose value is "275869398491926942" which matches to 2nd JObject value in the above mentioned JArray.

How Can I remove this entire object from the JArray such that my output looks like:

```
   {[  
      {
        "value": "275869398483537748",
        "label": "AbhiTest1"
      },      
      {
        "value": "275869398487731826",
        "label": "AbhiTest3"
      }
    ]}
```

Please guide me.

Comment: You can use `JTokenExtensions.RemoveAll<T>()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48937479/3744182) to [JArray - How to remove elements that are not contained in another list -fastest/best performance way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48934455/3744182) to remove multiple items from a `JArray` by value: `jarray.RemoveAll(IdsToDelete, i => (string)i["value"])`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/5RYKQ8.  Does that other question answer your also, or do you need a specific answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is not valid. You have to remove {} from both sides. After fixing you can use this code

```
JArray items = JArray.Parse(json);

items.Where(x=> idsToDelete.Contains( (string) x["value"])).ToList()
     .ForEach(tr => tr.Remove());
```